# Ubuntu FTP install and publish for LAN network

Tags: 14.04, server, ftp

New here. 
I am trying to install FTP (not SFTP or VSFTPD) server on `ubuntu` using command prompt version.

> sudo apt-get install ftp

It get installed successfully. But  not accessible on network when i am trying on windows browser like:

```
ftp://`IP_ADDRESS`
```

Do i have to do anything else?

Comment: What issues do you observe?

Comment: ftp server does not publish over LAN

Answer (score 0):

This command:

```
sudo apt-get install ftp
```

install a ftp client, not a server. That's why, see the output of:

```
$apt-cache show ftp
Package: ftp
....
Description-en: classical file transfer client
 This is the user interface to the ARPANET standard File Transfer Protocol.
 The program allows a user to transfer files to and from a remote network
 site.
Description-md5: ce93e483dfc5fef0655f73f364b3c01c
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
Supported: 5y
Task: standard, kubuntu-active, kubuntu-active
```

Comment: here i am trying to install ftp server. Whole problem is vsftpd runs fine but at client's end sh cannot transfer file gives error vsftpd server doesnt allow it.

Comment: I understand not your problem with 'sh cannot transfer file'. What are you exactly trying to do ?